# How much will it cost if I use TeamCity + EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, teamcity

Is there anyone have experience with using TeamCity on Amazon EC2?
How much will it cost on monthly basis? I will run the build process once a day (most of the time).

Or I should use other solution rather than EC2? We need to have online access to the build server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent use teamcity. But if you have a rought estimate of the application, you can use this:
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html